# submodule of completely reducible module is completely reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

I attempted to solve problems from the textbook 'Basic Abstract Algebra' by P.B. Bhattacharya, S.K. Jain, and S.R. Nagpaul, specifically Chapter 14, Section 4, but encountered difficulties in completing some of them,

> problem 14.4.1: Let $M$ be a completely reducible module, and let $K$ be a nonzero submodule of $M$. Show that $K$ is completely reducible. Also show that $K$ is a direct summand of $M$.

Here $$M=\oplus \Sigma_{\alpha \in \Lambda} M_\alpha$$
and $\exists \Lambda^{\prime} \subset \Lambda$ such that $M=K \oplus\left(\oplus \Sigma_{\alpha \in \Lambda'} M_\alpha\right)$.

$$
K\cong\frac{M}{\oplus \Sigma_{\alpha \in \Lambda^{\prime}} M_\alpha}=\frac{\oplus \Sigma_{\alpha \in \Lambda^{\prime \prime}} M_\alpha \oplus \Sigma_{\alpha \in \Lambda^{\prime}} M_\alpha}{\oplus \Sigma_{\alpha \in \Lambda^{\prime}} M_\alpha} \cong \sum_{\alpha \in \Lambda^{\prime \prime}} M_\alpha
$$

**Question 1**: I didn't understand the above line specially the way $M$ is written using product of direct sum.

> problem 14.4.3: Show that $\mathbb Z/(p_1 p_2)$ is a completely reducible $\mathbb Z$-module, where
> $p_1$ and $p_2$ are distinct primes.

<del>Before I give a trial to this problem, I start to work with an example. Take $\mathbb Z_4$, then I assume this can be written as $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$. but suspect $3\neq1+1$ can't be written as a direct sum here which seems not align with the definition. I feel that somewhere I need to use the fact that submodule of simple module $M$ is $(0)$ or $M$. I can't connect this with forward direction $(\implies)$.</del>

**Question 2:** Any hint/solution for problem 14.4.3 will be appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4$ has elements of additive order $4$ and $\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_2$ does not.

Comment: Ah, the distinct prime condition also rule out the case. @rschwieb Can you give any hint to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: I didn't understand the above line specially the way 
> is written using product of direct sum.

"Product of direct sum"?  Where do you see that? I'm guessing you are referring to $\bigoplus$ versus $\sum$.  There is no $\prod$ here.

I believe it is explicitly proven in this text that

> The following are equivalent:
>
> - $M$ is the sum of **all of** its simple submodules
> - $M$ is a direct sum of **some of** its simple submodules.

So if you believe the hint you have written here that there exists such a set $\Lambda'$, then this demonstrates that $K$ is completely reducible.

Comment: I guess I get the solution: For $K$ we can find a submodule of $M$ such that $M=K'\bigoplus K$. Then $M/K'\simeq K$, so it suffices to show that $M/K'$ is completely reducible. @rschwieb Any hints for the 2nd problem? And thanks for your response.

Comment: @N00BMaster Show it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/(p_1)\times \mathbb Z/(p_2)$ and argue those two are simple $\mathbb Z$ modules.

Comment: Does product of simple modules imply completely reducible? I didn't come across this theorem. Can you provide one or redirect me to any resource? without involving representation theory (google search give solution using representation theory) @rschwieb

Comment: @N00BMaster Finite products of modules are the same as finite sums, and most people _define_ complete reducibility via sums of simple modules.  Anyhow, [wikipedia should probably suffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_representation).